# how to show different prices for login and non-login user on cart page in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, price, addtocart

There are two prices one for login user and other one is for non login user but when i click add to cart button it show login customers prices to non-login customers please help how can i fix this.

Comment: Is this pricing set by customer group?

Comment: You can set prices by customer group

Comment: no i set prices for login or non-login users

Comment: But how do you do it?